# Extend Cart with an associationField in Shopware 6

Tags: javascript, php, associations, cart, shopware

I have a problem with the cart of Shopware 6.

I need to extend it adding a field to make an association with a "Shop" entity I've created, but I don't see in the documentation a way to do it.

Before to start I though that Carts were defined like other data structure in Shopware, using Entity and EntityDefinition class in php that you can extend with an EntityExtension, but this is not the case and I don't understand how to move in this case.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missunderstand the goal, but if it's only having some field in storefront, which can be maintained in BE, you might have a look at

https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/custom-fields

and if you want to take action by controller maybe this one?

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/custom-field

Comment: Thank you but no, you can add custom fields and extensions only on entity that are handled with Data Abstraction Layer, but Cart model is different, the question come out for this fact.